# Restrict custom post type by user Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, wordpress-roles

Can any help me?

I make the marketplace with a user role for example i call "seller" can sell his own music from dashboard. Then i have some problems and hope you can help me…

1. How do i make limit/restrict data access to the select dropdown "Connect Album Playlist" in the Product menu? where the user seller can only see his own data and unable to access / view others people music album data on the dropdown select?
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mL6InZpEJhDBXfHGmjHcK_ypXKeyc8EA/view
2. In the Release Album, same as the problem above. i want to make "Select Artist" dropdown, only display the name of artist created by that user?
   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fRyZSx2sYEnxgY-1QNVHEkwl761b-nsg

Then, i try to make custom code for limit user view data on select dropdown "Connect Album Playlist" on this picture:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KAB4xAz2XPxbYLEYayKX5WBIK3CNCw0D

but not work. can any help me with this code?

Many Thanks,
Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/

You can also follow the documentation found here: https://torquemag.io/2016/08/customize-wordpress-backend-clients/ if you want to write custom code. But with the number of edits you want to make, I think the plugin will be an easier and smoother solution.

Comment: Thanks for your advice..

I try with adminimize plugin but still not work.. This only way just custom code for this problem.. :(